# Using diff3 where filenames contain a dash (-)

Tags: diff, diff3

I'm trying to use diff3 in this way

> diff3 options... mine older yours

My problem is that I probably can't use it, since all my 3 files contain a "dash" within.
The manual mentions:
*At most one of these three file names may be `-', which tells diff3 to read the standard input for that file.*

so I probably have to rename filenames before running diff3.

If you know for a better solution or a workaround, please let me know about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *At most one of these three file names may be `-', which tells diff3 to read the standard input for that file.*

It does not state, that your filenames should not *contain* dash symbols. It simply says, that *if you want to*, you can put `-` instead of one of the names, in which case the standard input will be read instead of reading one of the files.

So, you can have as many dashes in your filenames as you like and diff3 should work just fine.

However, on Windows putting filenames in `""` for escaping space characters does not work, and I failed to find a suitable workaround. However, you can automatize the process of renaming files (if the files are relatively small, this would not even be too inefficient):

```
@echo off

copy %1 tempfile_1.txt
copy %2 tempfile_2.txt
copy %3 tempfile_3.txt

"C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\bin\diff3.exe" -E tempfile_1.txt tempfile_2.txt tempfile_3.txt
del tempfile_1.txt tempfile_2.txt tempfile_3.txt
```

Put this in a file like diff3.cmd, then run `diff3.cmd "first file.txt" "second file.txt" "third file.txt"`.

P.S. Moving files would be more efficient (if they are on the same disk volume as the script, which they are not in your case), you could even move them back to where they were initially, but for some time they would not be present at their original folder.

Comment: Thanks but I have problems with filenames that contain a dash

Comment: > "C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\bin\diff3.exe" -E "C:\RnD\setup_server - dev_intelligence.iss" "M:\RnD\setup_server - dev_intelligence2.iss" "M:\RnD\setup_server - dev_intelligence.iss"

Comment: I get this:
C:\PROGRA~2\KDiff3/bin/diff.exe: extra operand `dev_intelligence.iss''
C:\PROGRA~2\KDiff3/bin/diff.exe: Try `C:\PROGRA~2\KDiff3/bin/diff.exe --help' for more information.
C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\bin\diff3.exe: subsidiary program `C:\PROGRA~2\KDiff3/bin/diff.exe' failed (exit status 2)

Comment: Oh, you are using diff3 with Windows.. putting filenames in `" "` works for linux version, tried it just now. I suppose, the problem is not with dashes, but with spaces in filenames, looking for a workaround..

Comment: Wow, this is weird. diff itself works with files with spaces in names just fine, as long as you put them in `""`. diff3 however apparently "unwraps" its aarguments and then passed them to diff when it has to. So, no escaping symbols or whatever would (most probably) work, as the are all "processed" by diff3, leaving nothing extra for diff itself, which now gets something like `diff first file.txt second file.txt` instead of `"first file.txt" "second file.txt"`, which diff3 receives.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I have to rename filenames before passing them to diff3.

Comment: You can automate the process, though. With a batch script, I'll add an example one that does the trick to my answer soon.